# Angular CLI. Custom config service

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Всем доброго времени суток.

Помогите пожалуйста решить следующую проблему:
у меня имеется файл конфигурации приложения - app.config.json
В нем есть некоторая полезная информация. Так же есть интерфейс, соблюдающий структуру этого файла. Кроме этого есть сервис, который производит загрузку данных из файла в статический объект интерфейса. Однако при старте приложения складывается впечатление, что загрузки не произошло.

**app.config.json**

```
{
  "appUrl": "http://localhost:8080/asterisk-prime",
  "routes": {
    "device": "device",
    "extension": "extension",
    "queue": "queue",
    "queueMember": "queueMember"
  },
  "apiEndpoints": {
    "device": "/api/device",
    "extension": "/api/extension",
    "queue": "/api/queue",
    "queueMember": "/api/queueMember"
  },
  "stompEndpoint": "/socket"
}
```

**iapp.config.ts**

```
export interface IAppConfig {
  appUrl: string;
  routes: {
    device: string,
    extension: string,
    queue: string,
    queueMember: string
  };
  apiEndpoints: {
    device: string,
    extension: string,
    queue: string,
    queueMember: string
  };
  stompEndpoint: string;
}
```

**app.config.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AppConfigService {
  static settings: IAppConfig;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
  }

  loadConfig() {
    const configFile = 'src/assets/config/app.config.json';
    return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
      this.httpClient.get<IAppConfig>(configFile)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => {
          AppConfigService.settings = response;
          LoggerService.log('Config was loaded');
          resolve();
        })
        .catch(err => {
          LoggerService.error('Error while loading config.', err);
          reject(`Could not load file '${configFile}': ${JSON.stringify(err)}`);
        });
    });
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
...
export function loadConfig(appConfigService: AppConfigService) {
  return () => appConfigService.loadConfig();
}
...
providers: [
    AppConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: loadConfig,
      deps: [AppConfigService],
      multi: true
    }
  ],
...
```

Собственно, ошибка происходит в модуле роутинга во время инициализации роутов.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: '', component: HomePageComponent},
  {path: 'about', component: AboutPageComponent},
  {path: AppConfigService.settings.routes.device, loadChildren: './path/to/children.module#ChildrenModule'},
  {path: AppConfigService.settings.routes.extension, loadChildren: './path/to/children.module#ChildrenModule'},
  {path: AppConfigService.settings.routes.queue, loadChildren: './path/to/children.module#ChildrenModule'},
  {path: AppConfigService.settings.routes.queueMember, loadChildren: './path/to/children.module#ChildrenModule'}
```

Ошибка в браузере: `Cannot read property 'routes' of undefined`.

Comment: потому что `loadConfig` асинхронная функция, вы пытаетесь достучаться к свойству `routes` в тот момент, когда еще не пришел ответ от `src/assets/config/app.config.json`

Comment: после вашего апдейта непонятно какой вопрос вы задаете, если вы сами ответили на свой вопрос, то вынесите секцию updated в ответ и пометьте галочкой

Answer (score -1, accepted):

На данный момент решил вынести в отдельный файл конфигурации все, кроме роутов. Роуты оставил внутри приложения. Сам конфиг с роутами внедряю с помощью объявленного токена.

**iapp.config.routes.ts**

```
export interface IAppConfigRoutes {
  routes: any;
}
```

**app.config.routes.ts**

```
export let APP_CONFIG_ROUTES = new InjectionToken('app.config.routes');

export const AppConfigRoutes: IAppConfigRoutes = {
  routes: {
    device: 'device',
    extension: 'extension',
    queue: 'queue',
    queueMember: 'queueMember'
  }
};
```

**app.module.ts**

```
export function loadConfig(appConfigService: AppConfigService) {
  return () => appConfigService.loadConfig();
}
...
providers: [
    AppConfigService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: loadConfig,
      deps: [AppConfigService],
      multi: true
    },
    {
      provide: APP_CONFIG_ROUTES,
      useValue: AppConfigRoutes
    }
  ],
...
```

Использование AppConfigRoutes в компоненте (пример):

**header.component.ts**

```
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  private readonly appConfig: any;
  readonly angularLogo = require('../../../../assets/images/angular-white-transparent.svg');
  menuItems: any[];

  constructor(@Inject(APP_CONFIG_ROUTES) appConfig: IAppConfigRoutes) {
    this.appConfig = appConfig;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadMenus();
  }

  private loadMenus(): void {
    this.menuItems = [
      {name: 'Device', link: '/' + this.appConfig.routes.device},
      {name: 'Extension', link: '/' + this.appConfig.routes.extension},
      {name: 'Queue', link: '/' + this.appConfig.routes.queue},
      {name: 'Queue member', link: '/' + this.appConfig.routes.queueMember}
    ];
  }
}
```

Использование в `app-routing.module.ts` по сути осталось без изменений, только изменился объект.

```
...
{path: AppConfigRoutes.routes.device, loadChildren: './path/to/children.module#ChildrenModule'},
...
```